# jmeter test requests log a duration of 30secs for about 0.1% of tests

Tags: jmeter, windows-authentication, kerberos, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I'm running jmeter to load test a rest web service, and when I do a run with lots of tests, I start seeing some kind of hanging and timing-out of a few of the tests. It's always 30 secs, but I haven't put a time-out on my tests. It must be a jmeter thing.

I have double and triple checked that it's not on the server. The duration logging on tomcat shows that none of the requests take anything like so long.

I'm trying to get the load test right before I go around to my team and get everyone to really blast the server with it.

I see quite good stats, e.g. this is with 5 thread groups running 5 threads:

```
summary =  29120 in 00:05:23 =   90.2/s Avg:   254 Min:    31 Max: 30093 Err:    55 (0.19%)
```

The problem is the `Max` value - I get around 100 test requests which show an elapsed time of around 30 secs - this is a few of them from the output (look at the `elapsed time`):

```
timeStamp   elapsed label   responseCode    responseMessage threadName  dataType    success failureMessage  bytes   sentBytes   grpThreads  allThreads  Latency IdleTime    Connect
1.48975E+12 39093   POST data/save  200     POST data/save 2-3  text    TRUE        406 1192    5   25  30093   0   7
1.48975E+12 31033   GET data/load   200     GET data/load 1-2   text    TRUE        546 378 5   25  31033   0   4
```

I suspect the authentication process, but I can't be sure - there are no errors in the jmeter.log, there is a warning on every request:

```
RequestTargetAuthentication: NEGOTIATE authentication error: 
    No valid credentials provided 
        (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided 
            (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
```

I am using basic auth and not kerberos. The server normally implements only kerberos, but I enabled basic auth to aid testing.

Comment: Depending on library you set JMeter to use, it may have some default timeouts. You could set timeouts, but to something big, e.g. 900 sec (15 min) to see if they still happen. But as for reason, first suspect as always is port exhaustion: monitor port usage, and if you see that it reaches the limit, especially if a lot of ports are in TIME_WAIT state, then you found it. Remember, number of ports is not 32K by default on both Windows and Linux, but rather limited, and both Win/Linux are configured to long TIME_WAITs which may cause this sort of issue.